# Can you require at least 1 Spring Annotation of a certain type on a method?

Tags: java, spring, annotations

We have 2 types of annotations. One specifies an Authz check and the other explicitly specifies it does not: @AuthZCheck(type=...) and @NoAuthZCheck.

Is there a way to require at least one of those annotations on a method otherwise result in some sort of (preferably) compile-time error?

```
// this is ok
@AuthZCheck
public void getSensitiveInfo()

// this is ok
@NoAuthZCheck
public void getPublicInfo()

// this is NOT ok
public void getInfo()
```

**Edit1**
To clarify, this is not so much a functional issue as it is a policy issue. We allow other developers to write these methods, and we'd like them to think carefully about what type of AuthZ check it requires. Some of these truly do not need AuthZ checks, either because it's a public API or because the backend service does the AuthZ validation on its own.
But we've found cases where developers are leaving out the AuthZ check without thinking about it. They may have copy-pasted another method that didn't require it, without giving thought or even knowing about the AuthZ check feature.
We'd like to end that practice and require an explicit AuthZ annotation even one when AuthZ is not needed.

Comment: Not sure of a compile time error, but for runtime error, the constructor can get all the annotations on all methods with reflection and if there aren't any annotations, or the annotations that is needed, throw an exception. Or a unit test that checks the annotation can reconcile this as well and have a build error

Comment: Runtime reflection would create a performance hit. This code is in our edge gateway so would like to avoid that if possible. Unit test is interesting option but requires the developer to write it

Comment: You could just make the current @AuthZCheck behaviour the default on unannotated methods.

Comment: @tgdavies I'd still need a way to require AuthZCheck to make sure someone didn't just forget it

Comment: Just do whatever AuthZCheck does when you call a method that has no annotation.

Comment: @tgdavies I added an update to the question to clarify why I'm asking it. Sorry I wasn't clear earlier. Let me know if you understand why I need an annotation regardless of the functionality desired

Comment: At some point you must have a bit of code which calls `Method.getAnnotation` (or one of the other ways of getting annotations). Make that throw a runtime exception if there are no AuthZ annotations present -- that shouldn't be more expensive than whatever that bit of code does now. Or are these annotations getting woven into byte code at build time?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with an annotation
[Processor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/Processor.html?is-external=true).
The boilerplate implementation is below.

```java
package processing;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.annotation.processing.ProcessingEnvironment;
import javax.annotation.processing.Processor;
import javax.annotation.processing.RoundEnvironment;
import javax.annotation.processing.SupportedOptions;
import javax.lang.model.SourceVersion;
import javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement;

public class CheckAuthZ implements Processor {
    private ProcessingEnvironment processingEnv = null;

    @Override
    public Set<String> getSupportedOptions() { return Collections.emptySet(); }

    @Override
    public Set<String> getSupportedAnnotationTypes() {
        return Collections.singleton("*");
    }

    @Override
    public SourceVersion getSupportedSourceVersion() {
        SourceVersion[] values = SourceVersion.values();

        return values[values.length - 1];
    }

    @Override
    public void init(ProcessingEnvironment processingEnv) {
        this.processingEnv = processingEnv;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
        /*
         * Called for every TypeElement
         */
    }
}
```

You'll need to flesh out the logic of the `process()` method.  I've iterated
through and checked public methods for presence of at least one annoation.

```java
import ...AuthZCheck;
import ...NoAuthZCheck;

import static javax.lang.model.element.Modifier.PUBLIC;
import static javax.lang.model.util.ElementFilter.methodsIn;
import static javax.tools.Diagnostic.Kind.ERROR;

    @Override
    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
        for (TypeElement type : set) {
            for (ExecutableElement method : methodsIn(type.getEnclosedElements())) {
                if (method.getModifiers().contains(PUBLIC)) {
                    if (! (method.getAnnotation(AuthZCheck.class) != null || method.getAnnotation(NoAuthZCheck.class) != null)) {
                        processingEnv.getMessager()
                            .printMessage(ERROR, "No annotation");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

(Use WARNING instead of ERROR if you want the compilation to continue.)

And package into a JAR as a service provider.
`META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor` must contain:

```
processing.CheckAuthZ
```

Include that JAR on the compilation path for enforcement/detection.